# Make child div occupy full size of parent div

Tags: html, css

HTML FILE:

```
<div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <h2>ITEM NAME</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}


.one{
  display:block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:50%;
  height:325px;
  background-image: url('http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/lion_5-t2.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}

.two{
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
}

.two h2{padding-top: 20%;}
```

I want to make a hover transition effect, just like this website: 
[Here](http://www.bdinfosys.com/demo/?item=materialx)
You can see in portfolio when you hover the link another light-blue div expands. I guess it's using `transform: scale()` I tried to do something like that, but the second div is overpassing the size of the parent div. How may I fix that? What am I doing wrong?

Also, I have my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yywLoN) sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of the lion you are using has a transparent background which appears along the edges, giving the impression that div one is actually smaller than it is. Set the background on the div one to a background colour instead of an image, and you will see what i mean.

Comment: So everything is alright and I'm just dumb ;\ Thank you sir !

Answer (score 1):

i holp to help:

```
.one{
  display:block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:510px;
  height:330px;
  background-image: url('http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/lion_5-t2.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.two{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:10%;
  height:10%;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  margin-left:50%;
  margin-top:30%;
  opacity:0;
  border-radius:100px;
}

.two h2{margin-top: 20%; margin-left:20%;}

.one:hover .two{
  display:inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  margin:0px !important;
  border-radius:2px !important;
}
```